# rxjs angular2 iterate over array with infinite loop

Tags: angular, loops, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to create a loop that iterates over the elements in an array and I want to run the loop all over again once it completes.

I have started with the following snippet

```
 Observable.interval(1000).startWith(0)
                            .repeat()
                            .take(array.length)
                            .map(i => array[i])
                            .subscribe(item => { 
// some operation here 
             });
```

but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: place repeat after `array.length`. Actually you could just do `Observable.interval(1000).map(e => array[e % array.length])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you placed `take` after `repeat`, thus `take` will unsubscribe both the source and `repeat`.

Another option would be to just take the `% n`th element of the array, since `interval` emits numbers, we can use that. I noticed you added `startWith` to `interval`. Another way to get an interval that starts without delay is to use `timer(0, interval)`. Thus our final code might look like:

```
Observable.timer(0, 1000)
  .map(e => array[e % array.length])
  .subscribe(item => { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
function arrayRepeat(array) {
  var last = 0; 
  return function() {
    if(last === array.length) last = 0;
    return array[last++];
   }
}

Rx.Observable.create(obs => {
  let nextItem = arrayRepeat([1,2,3]);
  let in = setInterval(() => {
     obs.next(nextItem());
 }, 1000);
 return () => clearInterval(in);
}).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: Just wondering, Why do you not cancel the interval if the observable is unsubscribed? You could add `return () => clearInterval(interval)` inside `create`.

Comment: sure you can add it